# Are the fictitious names “Initech” and “Initrode” a play on words?

Tags: office-space

In the comedy *Office Space*, the protagonist works for a company called "Initech". At the end of the film, his co-workers take jobs at a competing company called "Initrode".

It seems that these names are meant to sound silly, but can someone here tell me if these fictitious names may also be some sort of word-play?

Comment: It seems to us over here in Yorkshire, 'isn't it heck'!
-- in it 'eck, we'd say.
IOW, is this hell or what?

Comment: Okay people, everyone please make up their minds if it's Initrode or Intertrode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the "ini" is supposed to be the phonetic equivalent of the word "any." So the people are working for "any tech" company. "Trode" is short for electrode.  As something that often plugs into something else, trode could reference a cubicle worker that can easily be plugged in to a new work environment. Not surprisingly, trode also apparently references a part of the male anatomy (see Urban Dictionary). In the movie, Peter mistakenly calls it Penetrode.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but is there any source for this Ini = Any concept?

Comment: another possibility: ini is a Windows standard for configuration files. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file.

Comment: ini as a prefix doesn't check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English. I think @apophenia-overload's answer makes more sense. Or at least it's a combination of the two answers.

Answer (score 51):

In the movie at around 41:56, as Peter takes down the banner previously put up by Bill Lumbergh, you can see another banner in the background that diagrams the company name's etymology:

> Initiative + Technology = INITECH

[image: Initiative + Technology = INITECH]

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the "ini" in initech and iniwas a short way to say "Innovation" as many tech businesses love to get that buzz word invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the fictitious name initech is to poke fun at how there are so many companies that have a varied spelling of this name: inotek, inateck, etc.